# How to invoke a method in spring boot, when table gets updated in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

My query is, how to invoke a method in spring boot project when a table is being updated in MySQL DB.

**Case 1:** Let's suppose I have a Mysql Db that is shared with two application and any particular table is updated frequently.

So, my issue is how can I notify another application (Spring-boot) to be aware of that update so that it can process that data.
**Note** I don't want to use the scheduler.

Thanks,

Comment: You may keep one log table and update that log table using mysql triggers associated with every table. From the spring boot application check the log table frequently using thread or use any push messaging mechanism.

Comment: @SumeshTG Any references.?

Comment: what kind of jdbc access do you use on your project? Are you using plain jdbc,  jpa, spring-repositories?

Comment: @bilak I'm using JPA

Comment: @PawanTiwari You may refer mysql triggers,events and from spring boot eventshttps://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with `Springboot` or any other application.

Question here is how should two applications(web or non web) communicate with each other.

With respect to communication, it depends on the requirement, whether you need Synchronous communication or Asynchronous communication.

If its **Synchronous** communication, you may use Rest Template or any other, but it blocks the current request, if other application is running as service.

If its **Asynchronous** communication(where you don't want to wait for result and client is not blocked), you use Message Brokers like Kafka, ActiveMq

I think you can either make async call feature of spring boot application, but consider what should you if the request fails?

Comment: @pawan, let me understand if my understanding is wrong. How is the update happens in dB, is it manual  or some application or program does the update in db, if yes what type application is that? And 8 can certainly sure that second application is spring boot application..

Answer (score 3):

There could be many solutions depending on which technology you use. If you are using Spring-data, then you can use [events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events) and from within eventhandler notify other application (you can use rest integration, amqp, ...)

Comment: I got your point but I have no control over another application that writes the table. I only have access to the DB. So whatever I want to do, I have to manage it with DB and my own application level. I'm thinking about using MySQL events but I don't know yet that it is feasible or not. Any suggestions.?

Comment: I don't know about mysql events, sorry. But if you don't have access to second application then it will become "unnotified" about changes. Maybe nothing will help  you here.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Appreciate that.